# Correct way to get an interface / object from an interface pointer?

Tags: vb.net, com-interop

Having known nothing about interfaces until now, I am having a remarkably hard time trying to actually implement the solution given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407961/vb-net-or-windows-api-how-to-find-out-which-icons-the-file-explorer-uses/40409271#40409271).

I think I am correctly getting the pointer to the IShellFolder interface, but I don't seem to be able to actually use that pointer. How do I get to a usable interface when having that pointer?

The code below shows what I am doing and where I suspect the problems.

First, my **interface delarations**:

```
' I have wrapped the interfaces in their own namespace, "BinarusShell".
' I have declared every interface's functions / subs in the same order as they are in the .idl files of the Windows Platform SDK 7.1.
' Every function / sub has the <PreserveSig()> attribute so that I can see the native return values when debugging.
' I'd like to keep the question as lean as possible, so I am showing only a few functions per interface.
' Of course, I have implemented all of them (as they are in the respective .idl file).

Namespace BinarusShell

  <ComImport()> _
  <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)> _
  <Guid("000214FA-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")> _
  Public Interface IExtractIcon

    ' The above GUID is the GUID for the UNICODE version of the interface, i.e. IExtractIconW.
    ' Therefore, the UNICODE variant of strings is used in the parameters of the following functions.
    ' See also the include files of the Windows SDK where this is done exactly that way as well.

    <PreserveSig()> Function GetIconLocation(ByVal uFlags As UInteger,
                                             <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeParamIndex:=2)> ByVal pszIconFile As String,
                                             ByVal cchmax As UInteger,
                                             ByRef piIndex As Integer,
                                             ByRef pwFlags As UInteger) As Integer

    ' ...
    ' Here comes the second function (IExtractIcon has only two) ...
    ' ...    

  End Interface

  <ComImport()> _
  <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)> _
  <Guid("000214E6-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")> _
  Public Interface IShellFolder

    <PreserveSig()> Function GetUIObjectOf(<[In]()> ByVal hwndOwner As IntPtr,
                                           <[In]()> ByVal cidl As UInteger,
                                           <[In]()> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex:=1)> ByVal apidl() As IntPtr,
                                           <[In]()> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> ByVal riid As Guid,
                                           <[In](), Out()> ByRef rgfReserved As UInteger,
                                           <Out()> ByRef ppv As IntPtr) As Integer

    ' ...
    ' Here come the other functions ...
    ' ...

  End Interface

End Namespace
```

Second, my **Windows API declarations**, and
third, the **function I want to implement** (this is where I am stuck):

```
' The Windows API declarations are in class Win32Api.
' This class is not wrapped in a certain namespace.
' To keep this question as lean as possible, I am leaving out my declarations of constants or GUIDs.
' I have taken all of them literally from the Windows Platform SDK 7.1.

Public Class Win32Api

  <DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
  Private Shared Function SHBindToParent(<[In]()> ByVal pidl As IntPtr,
                                         <[In]()> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> ByVal riid As Guid,
                                         <Out()> ByRef ppv As IntPtr,
                                         <Out()> ByRef ppidlLast As IntPtr) As Integer
  End Function

  <DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
  Private Shared Function SHGetKnownFolderIDList(<[In]()> <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)> ByVal rfid As Guid,
                                                 <[In]()> ByVal dwFlags As UInteger,
                                                 <[In]()> ByVal hToken As IntPtr,
                                                 <Out()> ByRef ppidl As IntPtr) As Integer
  End Function

' -----------------------------------------------------

' The function I would like to implement is in class Win32Api as well.
' The function at this stage does nothing which is useful for the outer world;
' It is just meant for code which I am stepping through with the debugger.
' The comments below show the result of every step and my understanding about what has happened.

  Public Shared Function IconTest() As Boolean

    Dim ui_ReturnFlags As UInteger
    Dim i_Result As Integer
    Dim intptr_CurrentPidlAbsolute As IntPtr,
        intptr_ParentIShellFolder As IntPtr,
        intptr_CurrentIExtractIcon As IntPtr
    Dim arintptr_RelPidList(0) As IntPtr
    Dim ishellfolder_Parent As BinarusShell.IShellFolder
    Dim iextracticon_Extractor As BinarusShell.IExtractIcon

    i_Result = SHGetKnownFolderIDList(FOLDERID_System, 0, 0, intptr_CurrentPidlAbsolute)
    ' The above seems to work. i_Result is 0 which means success, and
    ' intptr_CurrentPidlAbsolute has a reasonable value now.

    i_Result = SHBindToParent(intptr_CurrentPidlAbsolute, IID_IShellFolder, intptr_ParentIShellFolder, arintptr_RelPidList(0))
    ' The above seems to work. i_Result is 0 which means success, and
    ' intptr_ParentIShellFolder and arintptr_RelPidList(0) have reasonable values now.

    ' Now the PROBLEMS begin. I have no clue how to get an interface / object
    ' from intptr_ParentIShellFolder which I can use from within VB.net.
    ' Therefore, I just have tried the following (but believing that it is wrong):
    ishellfolder_Parent = DirectCast(Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(intptr_ParentIShellFolder), BinarusShell.IShellFolder)
    ' This does not throw an error, but I have no clue what actually is happening.
    ' Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown, as the name implies, should return an object which
    ' encapsulates an IUnknown interface, but I am giving a pointer to an IShellFolder
    ' interface, so I really wonder why it doesn't freak out. The original idea
    ' to try it that way was that I believe that IShellFolder inherits IUnknown,
    ' so it *eventually* could work that way. Could somebody comment about that?

    i_Result = ishellfolder_Parent.GetUIObjectOf(0, 1, arintptr_RelPidList, IID_IExtractIcon, ui_ReturnFlags, intptr_CurrentIExtractIcon)
    ' Now this is the point where I am completely puzzled. i_Result is still 0,
    ' which means success, but intptr_CurrentIExtractIcon is 0 as well, meaning
    ' that something has gone horribly wrong. According to my understanding of
    ' the MSDN documentation, GetUIObjectOf MUST NOT return S_OK if something
    ' has gone wrong; in other words, if it returns S_OK, then intptr_CurrentIExtractIcon
    ' MUST be set to a reasonable value. Could somebody explain what's happening?

    ' I have left out the rest of the function because it wouldn't make any sense
    ' to use the NULL pointer for any further action.

  End Function

End Class
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? From the docs, I got the impression that *every* folder item (virtual or not) and file exposes IExtractIcon.

Comment: Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown().  I doubt anybody is going to debug it for you when you don't post runnable code.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the reply. I already had tried that method (instead of what I have shown above), but couldn't get the IExtractIcon interface as well. In the meantime, I think I have found my error (see my answer below). Do you think this question and its answer are useful? If not, I'll just delete the whole thing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: When defining the `IShellFolder` interface in VB.net, I had forgotten to include the `BindToFolder()` function (you really shouldn't try to implement things at 03:00 a.m., notably if you had no clue of those things until 1 hour before).

Of course, as documented everywhere, this made the `IShellFolder` interface produce wrong results (again not really knowing what I am talking about, since `BindToFolder()` comes before `GetUIObjectOf()` in the interface definition, and the latter in turn comes before `GetDisplayNameOf()`, I could imagine that actually `GetDisplayNameOf()` has been called when my code called `GetUIObjectOf()`, which would explain the weird results).

Now I have corrected my `IShellFolder` definition (i.e. I have added the missing function) and have double-checked my other interface definitions (those were without errors), and everything works like expected.